# HTML5 Issues Chrome/Safari - Stops loading/Doesn't Load

Tags: google-chrome, video, safari, load, html5-video

site: http://www.ignitionpointventures.com

Hello All,

I am having html5 video loading issues on chrome/safari.  The basic idea is that there is a video container with video thumbnails on the right side.  I have created a separate html file containing each video's html5 video info to be placed in the video container.  On page load the first video automatically should load using jquery document ready, subsequently each thumb loading the appropriate html5/video.

Issue: 
On Chrome and Safari.

On Chrome the video on load does not appear.  On clicking the thumbs the first image of the video appears in the main video div, but appears to stop loading and will not play.

On Safari the video does not load at all.  When trying to play the file directly it has an error and the quicktime symbol shows up with a ? mark.

Here is an example of the html5 video

```
<video width="721px" height"406px" preload="auto" controls="controls">
        <embed src="http://www.ignitionpointventures.com/includes/video/v1/v1.mp4" width="721" height="406" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
        <source src="http://www.ignitionpointventures.com/includes/video/v1/v1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="http://www.ignitionpointventures.com/includes/video/v1/v1.ogv" type="video/ogg" codecs="theora, vorbis" />

         <source src="http://www.ignitionpointventures.com/includes/video/v1/v1.webm" type="video/webm" />

        <p>Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</p>
</video>
```

Here is the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#leftVideo').load('http://www.ignitionpointventures.com/includes/video/v1/v1.html'); 
    });

    $(function() {
        $(".v1").click(function(){
            $('#leftVideo').load('http://www.ignitionpointventures.com/includes/video/v1/v1.html');
        });
        $(".v2").click(function(){
            $('#leftVideo').load('http://www.ignitionpointventures.com/includes/video/v2/v2.html');
        });
        $(".v3").click(function(){
            $('#leftVideo').load('http://www.ignitionpointventures.com/includes/video/v3/v3.html');
        });
        $(".v4").click(function(){
            $('#leftVideo').load('http://www.ignitionpointventures.com/includes/video/v4/v4.html');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I checked the .htaccess file also

I know the videos are a bit large and could be an issue, but doubt this is the real problem.  yes the javascript could be more advanced.

Thanks!

Comment: In my chromium, video initialises on page load as expected. But it takes like 15 seconds. http://jsfiddle.net/nNq5a/2/